Stuck in i3 (forever?)
I've been using i3 und my ubuntu system for quite a while and today I wanted to change my mod key since keeping the left hand on homerow would be more ergonomic.
First I tried to map it to Mod5 which is supposed to be AltGr which semi worked on some commands, not on others.
Then I wanted to try right Control Key as my next option, which -after googling- I found out to be Mod3.
After starting in i3 I noticed Mod3 doesnt bind to anything (at least in my case). So now I'm in a position where I have no clue how to exit i3 (since no key appears to be mod, I tried every single one the keybord) and rebooting automatically starts in i3.
As far as I can see there is no way of ever exiting this loop? Because I cannot start a terminal to restore the config file or use the mouse in any meaningful way (logout, ... )
Anybody got any ideas?

have you tried holding the shift key during boot?

Switch to a different TTY with, e.g., Ctrl+Alt+F3, and log in there. You'll end up in your shell instead of in a GUI. If that doesn't work for some reason, you could pick recovery mode in GRUB, or boot from a LiveCD/LiveUSB and mount your filesystems. Either way, you'll then be able to reconfigure it.
